# Image View impacting surrounding fields

Tags: objective-c, ios7

In learning Objective-C and how to create ios apps, I'm following some tutorials using Xcode(5.1.1).

In this one, I have a 64x64 pixel Image view on the left hand side with a text field immediately to it's right stretching to the right hand edge of screen and a text view below it. In the simulator, when I add a photo, the photo is correctly sized but the text field is significantly enlarged and the text view has disappeared.

I figure it's an error on my part but I can't see where, so I need some guidance.

---

I tried, but Stackoverflow won't let me post images unless I have a reputation 10 or greater.

Comment: could you give some screenshots from your simulator as well as your .xib or storyboard file?

Comment: I tried, but Stackoverflow won't let me post images unless I have a reputation 10 or greater.

Comment: put it somewhere else and give a link to it then.

Comment: On a whim, I cleared all the constraints for the scene and the **problem disappeared**. Why? I don't know but I now need to figure out what constraints I can have without re-introducing the problem.